Sequelize (mysql): Max database connections reached frequently
I'm using Sequelize (v6.35) with MySQL + Express app, and I'm running into a problem where my database occasionally hits the max connections limit (500). This is happening once or twice a day, everyday. I have to restart the server manually when this error occurs.
I've configured the max connections in the connection pool, and also tried different options. I’ve been working on this for over a month and no solution found yet. My other projects with similar setup do not have this issue.
What could be causing the issue?
What does pool.max (Maximum number of connections in pool) do in Sequelize config?
Here's my sequelize instance.
// sequelize.js
export const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host,
  dialect: "mysql",
  logging: false,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
  },
  retry: {
    max: 3,
    match: ["ETIMEDOUT", Sequelize.ConnectionError],
  },
});

This is the main entry point.
// main.js
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(" DB connected!");
    createServer().then((app) =>
      app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(` Server ready at port: ${PORT}`);
      }),
    );
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(` Failed to connect db: ${err.message}`);
    sequelize.close();
  });


You close in the catch block.  What about when the call is successful?  You should close the connection regardless of success or failure.

500 connections, if shared properly, will do fine for a web app.   You just need to tune the size of the pool to the load on your service.  Make sure that you don't have long running transactions that keep ahold of connections for too long.

Where should I close the connection? sequelize.close closes all active connections and I'm not sure how to use it on success. @duffymo

I would find a way to monitor that pool and prove to myself that sequelize is closing all active connections.  How large is your user base?   500 connections is a large number.  A user only needs one for the duration of their operation.  A 500 connection pool can service a lot of requests.

Settings
All MySQL servers and all MariaDB servers limit the number of simultaneous connections. You can check the current value with:
mysql -e 'show variables like "max_connections"'
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 2000  |
+-----------------+-------+

You can change the current value with:
mysql -e 'set global max_connections = 2500'

But this value is reset on restart of the database server. To change the value permanently, you have to edit the config file in /etc/, sometimes /etc/my.cnf, sometimes /etc/mysql/... (depends on operating system). Add to section [mysqld]:
[mysqld]
...
max_connections = 2500

The maximum number of connections that have been in use simultaneously since the server started and the number of currently open connections can be queried as follows:
mysql -e 'show status where variable_name like "max_used_conn%" or variable_name="threads_connected"'
+---------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value               |
+---------------------------+---------------------+
| Max_used_connections      | 162                 |
| Max_used_connections_time | 2024-08-07 11:15:12 |
| Threads_connected         | 75                  |
+---------------------------+---------------------+

What is a good number of max_connections?
This question cannot be answered because the number of connections required depends on many things.
Typically, each website establishes exactly one connection per client to the database server. Therefore, for a first estimate, the maximum number of clients allowed by the web server (Apache, nginx,...) +200 should be used. The +200 then offers enough reserve for backend connections, such as those used by cron jobs.

Do I need to set the max_connections = 1000 if I want to have 1000 concurrent users?

@hThant yes! Better is 1000+100 (some more than needed).
